# How do you write a macro with chainable tokens?

Tags: rust

I'm not really sure how to phrase this, so the question title is pretty rubbish, but here's what I'm trying to do:

I can write this macro:

```
macro_rules! op(
  ( $v1:ident && $v2:ident ) => { Op::And($v1, $v2) };
  ( $v1:ident || $v2:ident ) => { Op::Or($v1, $v2) };
);
```

Which I can use like this:

```
let _ = op!(Expr || Expr);
let _ = op!(Expr && Expr);
```

What I want to do is to write an arbitrary sequence of tokens like this:

```
let _ = op!(Expr || Expr || Expr && Expr || Expr);
```

Which resolves into a Vec of tokens, like:

```
vec!(T::Expr(e1), T::Or, T::Expr(e2), T::Or, ...)
```

I can write a vec! like macro:

```
macro_rules! query(
 ( $( $x:expr ),* ) => {
   {
     let mut temp_vec = Vec::new();
     $(temp_vec.push($x);)*
     temp_vec
    }
  };
);
```

...but I can't see how to convert the arbitrary symbols (eg. &&) into tokens as the macro runs.

Is this possible somehow?

playpen link: http://is.gd/I9F5YV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it's impossible to capture arbitrary symbols matches during macroexpand: as the language reference says, "valid designators are item, block, stmt, pat, expr, ty (type), ident, path, tt". So the best I could suggest is to use "ident"-valid tokens, like "and"/"or" instead of "&&"/"||", for example:

```
macro_rules! query_op(
  ( and ) => { "T::And" };
  ( or ) => { "T::Or" };
  ( $e:ident ) => { concat!("T::Expr(", stringify!($e), ")") };
);

macro_rules! query(
 ( $( $x:ident )* ) => {
   {
     let mut temp_vec = Vec::new();
     $(temp_vec.push(query_op!($x));)*
     temp_vec
    }
  };
);

fn main() {
  let q = query!(Expr1 or Expr2 and Expr3 or Expr4);
  println!("{:?}", q);
}
```

Outputs:

```
["T::Expr(Expr1)", "T::Or", "T::Expr(Expr2)", "T::And", "T::Expr(Expr3)", "T::Or", "T::Expr(Expr4)"]
```